# Default shipping

Tags: shipping

Hi I have 2 shipping method

1. free shipping
2. USA shipping (This shipping method I have created)

now I want to add default shipping method to the cart is USA shipping, I did that , but when we come to checkout ant change the shipping method so shipping method is not changing can any one help me
I want once user will add a cart in item then default shipping will be USA shipping but on checkout user have 2 options and they can select any of them.